# Where do i put the suprasegmental to indicate the stressed syllable when transcribing in phonetics ipa

Tags: phonetics, ipa, transcription

In the words:

> *union*, /ˈjunjən/
> *discussion* /dɪˈskʌʃən/
> *banana* /bəˈnænə/
> *puppet* /ˈpʌpət/
> and
> *entertainment* /ˌɛntərˈteɪnmənt/

when transcribed where do I put the suprasegmental ' to indicate the stressed syllable?

Comment: You've already got the ' in the correct place to indicate the stressed syllable. What exactly is your question?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's a question about learning English, but about translation and phonetics.